# Suggestion of a SAT Solver written in C++ or haskell. Pros and cons

Tags: c++, haskell, sat-solvers

I need a SAT solver library or program, written either in C++ or haskell. I'd like to know why would you choose it and what are the pros and cons of that library/program. I need it to be as fast as possible, and easy to use.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: @Marcin: It's for a homework project, I need to use a sat solver to solve sudokus. My job is to codify the problem and feed it to the solver, but i would like to use a fast and light one, since my machine is not very powerful, and I'll need to make tests and benchmark-like comparisons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one (Fast SAT Solver):

http://dudka.cz/fss